# Remove endpoints of x-axis in MS Chart

Tags: c#, graph, mschart

I have a graph (see attached image) and I would like to remove the endpoints "2060" and "2020".  I want the spacing to remain the same. But I want to hide the labels 2060 and 2020.  Is there a way I can programmatically achieve this using MS Chart ?

[image: remove end labels]

Code for creating the axis:

```
            var area = new ChartArea();

        chart.ChartAreas.Add(area);
        chart.ChartAreas[0].Position.X = 5;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].Position.Y = 10;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].Position.Height = 80;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].Position.Width = 80;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = font10Point;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = font10Point;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Target Date Fund";
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "% Up Capture";

        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.TitleFont = font10Point;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Transparent;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Black;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].BorderColor = Color.Black;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].Position = new ElementPosition(0, 10, 75, 85);

        chart.Series[0].YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Crossing = 2060; 
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsReversed = true;
        area.AxisX.Minimum = 2020; 
        area.AxisX.Maximum = 2060; 
        area.AxisX.Interval = 10;
        area.AxisX.LineWidth = int.Parse("5");
        area.AxisX.MajorTickMark.LineWidth = int.Parse("5");
        area.AxisY.MajorTickMark.LineWidth = int.Parse("5");

        area.AxisY.Minimum = area.AxisY2.Minimum = 0;
        area.AxisY.Maximum = area.AxisY2.Maximum = 120;
        area.AxisY.Interval = area.AxisY2.Interval = 20;
        area.AxisY.LineWidth = int.Parse("5");
```

Comment: Do yo have a code or something? Please read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: @Soner Gönül right! forgot to add :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.labelstyle.isendlabelvisible.aspx) property:

```
area.AxisX.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible = false;
```